# How to catch any socket error in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, httplib

I am trying to check if a URL to a jpg is real. This code works, returns `True`if the jpg exists:

```
import httplib

def exists(site, path):

    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site)
    conn.request('HEAD', path)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    conn.close()
    return response.status == 200

print exists('uploads1.wikiart.org',
             '/images/vincent-van-gogh/vincent-s-bedroom-in-arles-1889.jpg')
```

However, if I  send it to a url that doesn't exist, like `'uploads1111.wikiart.org',`I get a socket error that says:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed 
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time
```

I searched for an answer and found something to do with the `errno` module but wasn't able to apply that code to my own successfully. I'm trying to catch any socket errors and return `False` if there is one.

Comment: Why can't you just catch `socket.error`?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to my own question:

```
import httplib
import socket


def exists(site, path):

    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site)
        conn.request('HEAD', path)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        conn.close()
        return response.status == 200

    except socket.error:
        return False
```